# Real Snow add-on has coloured snow in some areas

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm creating a simple winter scene, using the real snow add-on to make realistic snow. However, when I render the scene, the top of the snow appears to have some weird RGB colour effect (less noticeable due to the Denoise algorithm enabled). The only thing I changed with the snow is the roughness from `0.1` to `0.6`.

The Blender version is 3.3.

[image: Rendered Scene]

Snow shader editor:
[image: Snow shader editor]

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it probably has something to due with the _Subsurface Scattering_ values (perhaps the _subsurface radius_ RGB values are set to favor blue/cyan for snow).

Comment: I just added the image of the shader editor.

Comment: I'm not sure then - the colors favor blue but only slightly. Other than that, a Subsurface value of 1 is generally considered very high - maybe try lowering it? (around 0.2-0.3 is considered a common starting point)

Comment: That seemed to help, so thank you. I hope it gets patched soon enough!